# Terraform Output to set variables in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, terraform

I need to be able to store the environmental variables from Terraform Output in PowerShell and I am seeking an example of this. This is how far I have got. I am not sure what's the best way to do this:

```
$output = terraform output -json
$output

$json = Get-Content $output  | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach($prop in $json.psobject.properties) {
  Write-Host("##vso[task.setvariable variable=$($prop.Name);]$($prop.Value.value)")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should assist you with what you want:

```
$TerraformPath = "C:\tf\terraform.exe"

$Json_Output = (& $TerraformPath output -json) | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Change `$TerraformPath` to the location of your `terraform.exe`, I thought it would be best to take this route as I am unsure if you have terrraform in your environmental path.

All properties should then be in `$Json_Output`.